# match any line in a file

Tags: php, regex

I am not sure how to read a file and pull the 3 IPs out that matches the criteria in PHP. I tried using explode but that would explode all the spaces.... any kind of help I can get on this is great appreciated:

```
[May  7 16:30:08] NOTICE[5311] chan_sip.c: Registration from '"507" <sip:507@145.155.214.146:5060>' failed for '195.154.53.90:5068' - Wrong password
[May  7 16:30:48] NOTICE[5311] chan_sip.c: Registration from '"557" <sip:557@145.155.214.146:5060>' failed for '195.154.53.90:5087' - Wrong password
[May  7 16:31:26] NOTICE[5311] chan_sip.c: Registration from '"107" <sip:107@145.155.214.146:5060>' failed for '195.154.53.90:5107' - Wrong password
[May  7 16:31:43] NOTICE[5311] chan_sip.c: Registration from '"907" <sip:907@145.155.214.146:5060>' failed for '195.154.53.90:5084' - Wrong password
[May  7 16:31:58] NOTICE[5311] chan_sip.c: Registration from '"407" <sip:407@145.155.214.146:5060>' failed for '195.154.53.90:5101' - Wrong password
[May  7 16:32:17] NOTICE[5311] chan_sip.c: Registration from '"207" <sip:207@145.155.214.146:5060>' failed for '195.154.53.90:5083' - Wrong password
[May  7 16:32:31] NOTICE[5311] chan_sip.c: Registration from '"7" <sip:7@145.155.214.146:5060>' failed for '195.154.53.90:5113' - Wrong password
[May  7 16:32:57] NOTICE[5311] chan_sip.c: Registration from '"307" <sip:307@145.155.214.146:5060>' failed for '195.154.53.90:5117' - Wrong password
```

I tried using:

```
readfile(/var/log/asterisk/messages)
```

I'm just trying to get `$ip` to has `195.154.53.90` attached to it

```
$ip=$search[]
```

Comment: i would be inclined to use exec to call grep. some times the OS has the beast functions for the job

Comment: Why did you tried `readfile()`? Did you read the documentation of the function? At least after it failed - before posting here - you are expected to do it. -1

Comment: What's the criteria? Do you want to find the lines that contain `195.154.53.90`?

Comment: @Cristik i want to find any ip addresses...in that file and assign it to $ip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm probably going to regret this, but here it goes:

```
$ip = '195.154.53.90';
$result = preg_grep(preg_quote("/$ip/"), file('/var/log/asterisk/messages'));

print_r($result);
```

Based on the comments, to find any IP in the position where `195.154.53.90:5068` is found (surrounded by single quotes):

```
preg_match_all("/'(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}):\d+'/",
               file_get_contents('/var/log/asterisk/messages'),
               $ip);

print_r($ip[1]);
```

Comment: thanks for this, I actually wanted to pull the ip out.. not search for the ip... can you reverse it for me?

Comment: Edited:  Give @Cristik a +1 though it's a little complex.

Answer (score 2):

The following code will extract the IP's that follow the `failed for` text:

```
$lines = explode("\n", file_get_contents("/var/log/asterisk/messages"));
$ips = array_filter(array_map(function($item) {
    $matches = [];
    if(preg_match($item, "/'(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}):\d+'/")) {
        return $matches[1];
    }
    return false;
}, $lines), function($item) {
    return $item !== false;
});
```

What the above code does is that it first splits your log file into individual lines, the maps those lines to the result of a regular expression match, and afterwards if filters out the log lines that don't contain IPs.

If you need the IP's following `<sip:`, then you'll need to change the regular expression to the following: `/@(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}):\d+/`

Comment: thanks for this, however i got `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '{'` on line 4  -  I am looking for ips after the term `failed for `

Comment: i used `preg_match_all("/for '(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}):\d+/",` to pull out the tampering ips.